# Cálculo no programa C resulta em zero em qualquer valor do cálculo

Tags: c

Estou tentando fazer um cálculo de kwh, trabalho da facul. estou usando valores em float sendo que deve ser feito o cálculo do valor kwh*0.2, mas o resultado está sendo sempre zero. E não estou vendo nenhum erro no código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Note que para fazer cálculos com valores não inteiros o tipo de ser float ou double.

Comment: Evite postar imagens com seu código - cole o código em si, usando as funcionalidades de formatação do site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não se esqueça de inicializar a variável

Quando você imprime a variável não a necessidade de colocar o endereço de memória dela

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float calc = 0, kwh;
    printf("Escreva seu consumo em kwh: ");
    scanf("%f", &kwh);
    calc = kwh * 0.2;

    printf("Seu consumo e: %.2f \n", calc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: valeu cara resolvi.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("seu consumo e:%.2f \n", &calc);
// omite & para valor           ^ assim é endereço de memória
```

A forma correcta é

```
printf("seu consumo e:%.2f \n", calc);
```